Debug error Flutter with third party SDK - Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration
I am trying to integrate a third party android SDK in my Flutter project. After many trouble shooting, code probably is going to look like a Frankestein, I do not understand what I am missing or doing wrong. I keep getting the following error:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://jitpack.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
 Required by:
     project :app
   > Could not find io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://jitpack.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
   - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355/x86_debug-1.0.0-c4cd48e186460b32d44585ce3c103271ab676355.pom
 Required by:
     project :app

     * Try:
     > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
     > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
     > Run with --scan to get full insights.

     * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

     BUILD FAILED in 11s
     Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My android/build.gradle file is
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
    url 'http://download.flutter.io'
    allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    

    }
 }


 plugins {
         id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "1.5.31" apply false
           id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' version '1.0.0'apply false
 }


     rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
     subprojects {
         project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
     }
              subprojects {
         project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
     }


     tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
     }

and my app/build.gradle file is
         plugins {
         id 'com.android.application'
         id "kotlin-android"
         id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
         id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
     }

     def localProperties = new Properties()
     def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
     if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
         localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
             localProperties.load(reader)
         }
     }

              def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
     if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
         flutterVersionCode = '1'
     }

     def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
     if (flutterVersionName == null) {
         flutterVersionName = '1.0'
     }

     android {
namespace "com.example.ble_prova"
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

         defaultConfig {
             // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/         build/application-id.html).
             applicationId "com.example.ble_prova"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-         gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
             }
         }
     }

     flutter {
         source '../..'
     }

              dependencies {
         implementation project(path: ':mokosupport')
         implementation files('app\\libs\\gradle-wrapper.jar')
         implementation files('app\\libs\\mokoBleLib.jar')
         implementation files('app\\libs\\mokoSupport.jar')
         implementation files('gradle\\wrapper\\gradle-wrapper.jar')
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
         implementation files('/Users/username/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/         android-                                    arm64-release/flutter.jar')
     }

My setting.gradle file is
     pluginManagement {
         def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}
settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { 
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

         plugins {
             id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0" apply false
             id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
         }
     }
     dependencyResolutionManagement {
         repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
         repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    gradlePluginPortal()
         }
     } 

     rootProject.name = "ble_prova"

     include ':app',':mokosupport'

I have removed the strings
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "com.android.tools" version "7.5.1" apply false

because I thought it was a problem of compatibility between Android Tool and Gradle version, but the error is the same.
Please help me see what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks
